# Repetitions with regexes in Firebird

Tags: regex, firebird

Hello all :) I'm having trouble with Firebird's `SIMILAR TO`, which is supposed to provide regex-like behavior.

```
'aaaaa' SIMILAR TO 'a{2,}'     -- true
'aaaaa' SIMILAR TO '(_)\1+'    -- false
```

The `\1` does not seem to be interpreted by Firebird. `\` is not even a special character.

How can I match on character repetition? (or use a back-reference?)

Comment: `(_)\1+` or `(a)\1+`?

Comment: Do you mean `(.)\1+`?

Comment: @devnull `(_)\1+`, I want repetitions of any character.

Comment: @ohaal I'd like `(.)\1+` to work properly, the wildcard in FireBird is `_`

Comment: Apparently, FireBird `SIMILAR TO` [does not support backreferences.](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-similar-to.html)

Comment: @ohaal Ah :/ Do you see another way I could identify repetitions without backreferences?

Comment: @BenoitParis Without backreferences I don't see any possible way to do it. Also, regex for databases was always not that powerful. I think regex isn't meant to be used on the DB layer to begin with.

Comment: The regular expression format of Firebird is the one defined by the SQL Standard committee (and also used in the PostgreSQL implementation of `SIMILAR TO`). It is a monster created from parts of the `LIKE` syntax and regular expressions...