# Repetitions in field in Firebird without regex

Tags: sql, firebird, data-quality

I'm trying to craft a query which rejects a row when some field is all the same characters. Ie. I want to select people named Smith but not people named aaaaaa or bbbb.

I can't use regexes, as [Firebird's `SIMILAR TO` doesn't have backreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432507/repetitions-with-regexes-in-firebird).

How would you do it?

Comment: You could try to look for an UDF that does this (I couldn't find one though), or write your own UDF for this.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I thought about doing one. The SQL I posted answers a large part of business problems though, so I'll stick to it. 

I did not know that proper regexes were not in the standard. I come from the Oracle world where there is `REGEXP_LIKE`. And Oracle doesn't respect the Standard: no `SIMILAR TO`. It is a shame the standard comittee don't think is is worth to add regex and that they stick to the monstruous thing you say `SIMILAR TO` is.

I see you develop and maintain Jaybird. Thanks a lot for the good work :)

Comment: Did you programmed Stored Procedures in FB?

Answer (score 0):

Meh, this is not what I wanted, but this will do. It works on aaaaaa, but wouldn't on abbbbbb.

```
SELECT *
FROM PEOPLE
WHERE replace(upper(NAME), substring(upper(NAME) FROM 1 FOR 1), '') = ''
```

Comment: The regular expressions provided by Firebird is the one defined by the SQL standard committee, and is (or should be) the same as the one implemented for the `SIMILAR TO` implementation of PostgreSQL.

Comment: That would give false positive on the strings that were empty already. Hopefully not on Null ones